# Asp.net Core Api Custom Routing

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to access to my .net core controller action somewhat like this

api/myController/myAction

Tried the following and didn't work:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"); });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show some code what you have tried so far

Comment: `app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});`
I tried This it didnt work

Comment: Add api before controller like "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"

Comment: It doesn't work either.. Any ways I got it solved after research..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After spending some trial error. I found that we have to decorate that Action method Something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("[action]")]
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> myAction()`
```

And it worked.

I found out problem was if you don't route to action method as above it will take default action name as index and try to route it.

This Route parm forces it to look for action name ie myAction for this example. and you should have `[Route("api/[controller]")]` decoration for your controller too.

Comment: this code alone does not help you achieve the above. you must have missed out something.

Comment: The problem is it will take action=index if you don't decorate it with `[Route("[action]")]` When you do it will be solved.

Comment: the solution is still not valid. With what you have posted, `Route` attribute would just override the configured default route, thus making the route simply "myAction" not "api/controller/myaction"

Comment: When you generate a controller by default it will be routed to following `[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class myControllerController : ControllerBase` all we need to add is what i mentioned above in answer

Comment: true, that is the missing part. the default route line is pointless in this context since you have completely overridden.

Comment: It will not override.. it is continuation of that route..
Try an example it will work fine..

Comment: I know the example will work. I am talking about relevant and irrelevant codes. The last line of code in your answer is irrelevant and the line you posted in your comment is relevant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185869/discussion-between-chetan-sharma-and-neville-nazerane).